# Как можно запретить работу скрипта PHP во время строки адреса, а разрешить работу только в iframe?

Tags: javascript, php, iframe

Сабж: нужно не запретить работу скрипта php в iframe, а сделать доступным только строго в iframe, при адресной строке браузера ссылка скрипт.php из iframe не должна работать и вывести только 403. Возможно ли?

Comment: https://tproger.ru/explain/xyproblem/

Answer (score 1):

```js
if( window.self !== window.top ){
  alert('iframe')
}
```